# how to pass object by using ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, object

I need to pass the object f by ajax
because it is extension of this form,

custom_fields the fields are in accordance with the selection of the select,
forming a nested_form in custom_fields

```
#post.js    
function load_custom_fields(id){
       var url = "/post_categories/"+ id +"/custom_fields";
        $.post( url, { f: '<%= f %>' }, function( data ) {
          $("#custom_fields").html(data);
        });
    }
```

in _html.erb

```
     #_html 
<%= simple_nested_form_for @post, html: { multipart: true}, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.association :post_category, input_html: { class: 'form-control input-lg', onchange: 'load_custom_fields(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)' }, required: true,include_blank: "Escolha o tipo de campo " %>
     </div>
   <div id='custom_fields'></div>
 <% end %>
```

help me!

Comment: Interesting, I also wanna know the answer. According to me its not possible. f is a form builder class and you made it string in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

in the same js file, I create an object and use it. It works for me.

Can be created in the model as well.

Do not forget the single quotes

```
   '<% @pedido = Pedido.new %>'
'<% @pedido.pedido_produtos.build %>'
'<%= form_for @pedido do |f| %>'

'<%if @elementos == 0 %>'
$('#addinfoproduto').html("%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'shared/infoproduto', locals: { produto: @produto, object: @object, f: f}))%>")
'<%else %>'
var novoid = "addinfoproduto"+ '<%=@elementos %>'
$("#"+novoid).html("%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'shared/infoproduto', locals: { produto: @produto, idelemento: @elementos, object: @object, f: f}))%>")
'<%end %>'

'<% end %>'
```